# How do I install the commerceguys libraries?

Tags: theming

While installing Drupal Commerce 8.x-2.x-dev on Drupal 8.0.0-rc4, I'm greeted by the announcements.

> Commerce Price requires the commerceguys/intl library.
> Commerce Tax requires the commerceguys/tax library.
> Address requires the commerceguys/addressing library.

How do I that? It's probably so obvious that I'm overlooking it.

> [image: Message concerning required external libraries for Drupal Commerce 2.x]

Comment: Unfortunately, even after installing, the error message keeps appearing, preventing me from activating the Drupal Commerce submodules

Comment: Commerce has install docs for this: http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/install.html

Answer (score 4):

Download composer_manager into your modules directory.

From the Drupal root directory, initialize composer_manager, and run it for the first time:

```
php modules/composer_manager/scripts/init.php

composer drupal-update

composer dump-autoload
```

This will download the required libraries into the root vendor/ directory.

Enable modules now.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into an issue where even though I installed via `composer require commerceguys/addressing` it picked up the stable release instead of the release required by `drupal/address`, and the error message is confusing.

However once I confirmed that the drupal module required a dev release rather than the stable release I was able to install by changing the version in composer.json to `^1.0` instead of `^0.8`.

In development it is often easier to checkout modules via git into the modules directory rather than to use the complexity of composer projects or requiring via `--prefer-source` because composer will remove development/IDE directories that you may be using in order to hack or develop on those modules. Thus it is important to pay strict attention to those modules' individual composer.json files and provide the correct versions when running `composer require` in the drupal root directory.

Answer (score 1):

We have documented this process on the Drupal Commerce docs website at http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/index.html. These are the commands to run on an existing site.

```bash
drupal module:download composer_manager 
php modules/contrib/composer_manager/scripts/init.php
composer drupal-update 
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to the composer.json file.

```json
"require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^8.8",
    **"commerceguys/intl": "dev-master",
        "commerceguys/addressing": "dev-master"**
    },
```

Then run `composer update`, clear the cache, and try again to install Address. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The link to the installation instructions listed earlier seems to have changed.  [Developer guide > Installation and updates > Installing](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation) says that the following command will download Drupal 8 and Commerce 2.x with all dependencies in the *mystore* folder.

```bash
composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev
```