# Module installation issue

Tags: 8

I am attempting to install modules on Drupal 8 but I'm getting a failure that says i need to install commercial guys, addressing and zone libraries. When I put the libraries inside the library directory: (public_html/mysite.com/sites/all/libraries)  I still get this error. I'm thinking I need to install them somewhere else since I'm using Drupal 8.

Also, there is a module called composer manager which according to my reads automatically installs needed libraries for modules. The problem i'm facing is that its asking to use the command prompt to install them. see the link below:

[How to install the commerceguys libraries for Drupal Commerce 2.x?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181162/how-to-install-the-commerceguys-libraries-for-drupal-commerce-2-x)

Im using Hostgator hosting, how can I install this using command prompt? Which command prompt do I use, Drush, Bash?

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to ask the Hostgator support if/how they support that.

One alternative is setting up and running those commands locally, that will download the necessary files and you can then upload them.

Comment: Agreed. Given you should be using composer to install the libraries, trying to manually place them in your site's libraries directory just won't work. You'll almost certainly need to run the commands locally and upload the result once it's done.