# How do I install the dependencies without Composer?

Tags: commerce

I'm installing Drupal Commerce on a Vardot installation and I get the following error.

> Address requires the commerceguys/addressing library.

There is a solution for this on
[How to install the commerceguys libraries for Drupal Commerce 2.x?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181162/how-to-install-the-commerceguys-libraries-for-drupal-commerce-2-x) but it requires Composer and I don't want it.

How do I install the dependencies without Composer?

Comment: You should try the [Ludwig](https://www.drupal.org/project/ludwig) project, supported by Drupal Commerce. See also [this video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLR5EsqS8UM).

Comment: You should definitely install `composer` as it's the simplest way to do that. BTW Drupal itself & its dependencies can be installed via composer as well.